# Sync issue in collection fetch backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i'm fetching a collection but i've problem because into the collection the function parse use an another ajax call.So if i try to console.log the response of fetch after the fetch linecode but it is ever undefined.

Function call fetch:

```
  friends: function(){

    var amici=new Amicizie();
    var amicilist=amici.fetch();


    console.log(amicilist);<---undefined,because executed before  fetch
```

collection called:

```
    var obj={};

    var Amicizie = Backbone.Collection.extend({


    url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User/',

    parse: function(data) {

    var cur_user=Parse.User.current().id;

    $.ajax({

    type: 'GET',

    headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'qS0KL***EM1tyhM9EEPiTS3VMk','X-Parse-REST-API- 
    Key':'nh3eoUo9G***JIfIt1Gm'},

    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/?where=....",

    success: function(object) {
      console.log(object );
      obj=object;
      console.log(obj );

    },
    error: function(data) {

      console.log("ko" );
    }





    });

    return obj.results;

}


});
```

return Amicizie;

});

Comment: I think the are better ways to do this. Backbone.sync is _already_ a wrapped ajax call, so the route you're following may lead to a lot of headache. Can you clarify what that nested ajax call gives you?

Comment: i use the nested ajax call to make a query on db

Comment: Parse is a function you can override to modify structure of data before it gets stored into models. You shouldn't use any async stuff there. What's the db query giving you in terms of logic? Is it something you could do after having completed the fetch flow (which is, after parse is called and the models have been refreshed)?

Comment: the db query get a relational field that i can't find on model after fetch

Comment: Uhm. I would go with a fetch().complete(function() {...}) and place your additional ajax call in place of those "..."

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'complete' of undefined.Why?